devexpress XtraUserControl view control navigate into frame
Hello I have devexpress MainController(RibbonForm) created from template.
And have 2 Buttons Employees and Customers
I want to open Employees View into frame when Employees button clicked
I want to open CustomersView into frame  when Customersbutton clicked
My codes under below
**MainController.cs**


using DevExpress.XtraBars;
using DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views;
using DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace aza.Forms
{
    public partial class MainController : DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
    {
        XtraUserControl employeesUserControl;

        XtraUserControl customersUserControl;
        public MainController()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            employeesUserControl = CreateUserControl("Employees");
            customersUserControl = CreateUserControl("Customers");


            accordionControl.SelectedElement = employeesAccordionControlElement;
        }
        XtraUserControl CreateUserControl(string text)
        {
            XtraUserControl result = new XtraUserControl();
            result.Name = text.ToLower() + "UserControl";
            result.Text = text;
            LabelControl label = new LabelControl();
            label.Parent = result;
            label.Appearance.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 25.25F);
            label.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            label.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            label.AutoSizeMode = LabelAutoSizeMode.None;
            label.Appearance.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;
            label.Appearance.TextOptions.VAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.VertAlignment.Center;
            label.Text = text;
            return result;
        }
        void accordionControl_SelectedElementChanged(object sender, SelectedElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Element == null) return;
            XtraUserControl userControl = e.Element.Text == "Employees" ? employeesUserControl : customersUserControl;
            tabbedView.AddDocument(userControl);
            tabbedView.ActivateDocument(userControl);
        }
        void barButtonNavigation_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            int barItemIndex = barSubItemNavigation.ItemLinks.IndexOf(e.Link);

            accordionControl.SelectedElement = mainAccordionGroup.Elements[barItemIndex];


        }
        void tabbedView_DocumentClosed(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
        {
            RecreateUserControls(e);
            SetAccordionSelectedElement(e);
        }
        void SetAccordionSelectedElement(DocumentEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tabbedView.Documents.Count != 0)
            {
                if (e.Document.Caption == "Employees") accordionControl.SelectedElement = customersAccordionControlElement;
                else accordionControl.SelectedElement = employeesAccordionControlElement;
            }
            else
            {
                accordionControl.SelectedElement = null;
            }
        }
        void RecreateUserControls(DocumentEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Document.Caption == "Employees") employeesUserControl = CreateUserControl("Employees");
            else customersUserControl = CreateUserControl("Customers");
        }

        private void employesButton_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void customersButton_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}




**EmployeesView.cs**

`using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace aza.Forms
{
    public partial class EmployeesView: DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public EmployeesView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
`




**CustomersView.cs**

using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace aza.Forms
{
    public partial class CustomersView: DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public CustomersView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

Thanks for help.I can't find where I made a mistake
I couldn't run the clicked function

Do you get an error message? You need to better explain the expected behavior and what is currently happening.

@Brendon nope .
